# Azure Devops exclude job if branch tag is present

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline

My Azure DevOps pipeline has 3 jobs. One builds the project for production and the other builds it for testing and the last publish artifacts. When I push to release branch, it triggers all of 3 jobs, but they can take 10-15 minutes to finish. What I'm trying to achieve is exclude testing job if a tag is present on the commit or something like that.

Ex. Don't trigger test job if branch tag has "hotfix". Tryed "Run this job with conditions" in job's settings with this value "not(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/hotfix'))" but if I push something to release with hotfix tag it still runs.

Thanks

Comment: it might be easier if you copied/pasted the actual code in your yml file

Comment: I'm not using yml files, just classic version

Comment: @RubénM, I update my answer and share you about how to set it in the classic edit. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend you can use the conditions:

```
condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/test')
```

And this means if you want the test job to run, then you need to push something to release with test tag. We cannot use the value "`not(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/hotfix'))`"
On my test, if I push the commit release with hotfix tag, then the test job will be skipped.
[image]

**Update:**

We can use the Custom conditions in Additional options, and set it as :

```
eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/test')
```

[image]

More details, you can refer this doc: [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)